# Using noah cookbook to coordinate server installation?

Tags: chef-infra

I want to coordinate chef cookbook inter-server, that is, run chef-client on Server1 and Server2, but chef-client on Server2 will not run until Server1's chef-client run finishes. I stumbled on a cookbook called [Noah](https://github.com/lusis-cookbooks/noah), but the instructions on the page are at most vague. I know I probably want to use the noah_block LWRP, but how do I actually setup everything else before that? Has anyone used this cookbook, and to please give me pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Noah is a dead project](http://blog.lusis.org/blog/2013/01/20/future-of-noah/). If you are looking for a distributed coordination system, that's going to be a pretty difficult thing to do. Well outside the scope of a SO question, more like "I hope you don't mind spending $100k on this". The more common and easier approach is to use an orchestration tool like Fabric or RunDeck to handle this. Some other options include Chef Push Jobs, MCollective, SaltStack, Ansible (yes I know those two are also config management tools as well), and Capistrano.

Comment: Wow, it looked promising. I will look at Chef Push jobs since I do have Chef 12 Enterprise

Comment: There is no such thing as Chef 12 Enterprise. If you have Enterprise Chef 11  or Chef Server 12 you could look at Push Jobs. I would still vote for RunDeck as a far more proven option though.